# pandas and numby to read csv and convert it from 2d vector to 1d with ignoring diagonal values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

My csv file looks like this:

```
0  |0.1|0.2|0.4|
0.1|0  |0.5|0.6|
0.2|0.5|0  |0.9|
0.4|0.6|0.9|0  |
```

I try to read it row by row, ignoring the diagonal values and write it as one long column like this:

```
0.1
0.2
0.4
0.1
0.5
0.6
0.2
0.5
0.9
....
```

I use this method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\soso-\Desktop\SVM\DataSet\chem_Jacarrd_sim.csv")
row_vector = np.array(data)
result = row_vector.ravel()
result.reshape(299756,1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'chem':result})
df.to_csv("my2.csv")
```

However the output ignores the first row and reads the zero's like follows:
how can I fix it?

```
0.1
0
0.5
0.6
0.2
0.5
0
0.9
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the datframe you have:

```
0  |0.1|0.2|0.4
0.1|0  |0.5|0.6
0.2|0.5|0  |0.9
0.4|0.6|0.9|0
```

which I saved as the `ffff.csv`df, you need to do the following thing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("ffff.csv", sep="|", header=None)
print(data)
row_vector = np.array(data)

# Create a new mask with the correct shape
mask = np.zeros((row_vector.shape), dtype=bool)
mask[np.arange(row_vector.shape[0]), np.arange(row_vector.shape[0])] = True

result = np.ma.array(row_vector, mask=mask)
result = result.compressed()

df = pd.DataFrame({'chem':result})
df.to_csv("my2.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

which returns:

```
    chem
0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.4
3    0.1
4    0.5
5    0.6
6    0.2
7    0.5
8    0.9
9    0.4
10   0.6
11   0.9
```

Comment: thank you, but this error occur 'numpy.ma.core.MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size is 299756, mask size is 299209' . Also i dont want to drop the first row, it seems that it has been dropped @Serge de Gosson de Varennes

Comment: My apologies. I corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit shorter

- assuming you have 2d numpy array

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(3,3)

# array([[0.12964821, 0.92124532, 0.72456772],
#        [0.26063188, 0.1486612 , 0.45312145],
#        [0.04165099, 0.31071689, 0.26935581]])

arr_out = arr[np.where(~np.eye(arr.shape[0],dtype=bool))]

# array([0.92124532, 0.72456772, 0.26063188, 0.45312145, 0.04165099,
#        0.31071689])
```